# jQuery change added text inside textarea from input text on delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update textarea value from input text field real-time.

With this code I can do it but if you delete some characters then everything is getting added repeatedly. How can I just add what if is in the input field or nothing if it's empty?

So if the `name` field is empty then only remain **My name is:**

and same with the `email` field

```js
$("#name").keyup(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    text = text.replace("My name is: " , "My name is: " + name)
    $('textarea').val(text);
});

$("#email").keyup(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    text = text.replace("My email is: ", "My email is: " + email)
    $('textarea').val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Name</b> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
<b>Email</b> <input type="email" name="email"  id="email" required/>
<b>Message</b>

<textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="message">Hello, xyz!

My name is: 

My email is: 

</textarea>
```

Comment: `text.replace("My name is: " , "My name is: " + name)` does not make much sense. Your code is never going to remove the previous name. You are going to have to make your regular expression also match anything up until the end of the line.

Comment: @freedomn-m Really yes....

Comment: Is there a reason you chose a `textarea` rather than `<div id=message>My name is:<span id=myname></span></div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the text gets updated on each key press, so that replacing only the `My name is:` string doesn't remove the user's input.

To fix this you can use a regular expression which targets the line prefix and includes all content up to the following line break:

```js
$("#name").keyup(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  text = text.replace(/My name is: .*/gi, "My name is: " + name)
  $('textarea').val(text);
});

$("#email").keyup(function() {
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  text = text.replace(/My email is: .*/gi, "My email is: " + email)
  $('textarea').val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Name</b> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
<b>Email</b> <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
<b>Message</b>

<textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="message">Hello, xyz!

My name is: 

My email is: 

</textarea>
```

In addition, this logic can be DRY'd up. Note that the `textarea` has also been made `readonly` so that it can't be amended outside of interacting your `input` elements.

```js
let $textarea = $('textarea');

$(".user-input").on('input', e => {
  $textarea.val((i, v) => {
    let re = new RegExp(`My ${e.target.name} is: .*`, 'gi');
    return v.replace(re, `My ${e.target.name} is: ${e.target.value.trim()}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Name</b> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="user-input" required/>
<b>Email</b> <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="user-input" required/>
<b>Message</b>

<textarea rows="20" cols="20" name="message" readonly>Hello, xyz!

My name is: 

My email is: 

</textarea>
```